# Two lookups to the same entity pre-filled in creation mode

Tags: javascript, dynamics-crm-2011, dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-online, dynamics-crm-2015

I have a customised Entity X and I have two lookups to account, and when I want to create a record of entity X from account, I find myself with a form with the two lookups of account prefiled by the name of the account I started from.
I need to make one of those two lookups not pre-filled by the name of the main account in creation mode, is it possible to do this?
Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 2):

Clear the field in the form's `onload` event, like this:

```
if (Xrm.Page.ui.getFormType() === 1) {
   Xrm.Page.getAttribute("new_myaccountid").setValue(null);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Go to Relationships for your entity and find the Relationship for the Lookup that you want left blank. Open it and go to Mappings and remove the mapping to the parent account.

Mappings define which fields get mapped from the parent to the child when creating a child from the parent.

Comment: Thanks Josh for your answer but I've already tried this but The Crm doesn't let me delete the mapping and tell me: Impossible de supprimer le mappage de champ
Impossible de supprimer un ou plusieurs mappages de champs, car ils sont utilisés par la plateforme Microsoft Dynamics CRM